# XSL IF two variables never appear to compare

Tags: xslt

When printing the two variables $cID and $uID i get the two printed and can see the data they contain.

When attempting to compare the two the result never appears true even though when printed there should be some cases.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('C:/Users/Scott/Desktop/Uni/dbe/ass1/DBE-work1/DBE-work1/DBE-A1/tweets.xml')">
 <xsl:for-each select='tweets/tweet'>
  <tweet>
   <xsl:variable name="cID" select="user_id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select='$uID'/>
    <xsl:value-of select='$cID'/>
    <xsl:if test="$cID=$uID">
     <xsl:value-of select='$uID'/>
     <xsl:value-of select='$cID'/>
    </xsl:if>
  </tweet>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The current output is

```
 <tweets>
      <tweet>90484508
    15985455
        </tweet>
      <tweet>90484508
    90484508
        </tweet>
      <tweet>90484508
    21157904
        </tweet>
      <tweet>90484508
    90484508
        </tweet>
      <tweet>90484508
    90484508
        </tweet>
    </tweets>
```

However when there is two matching id's, in this example the last two. It should be producing duplicate results.

Comment: What is (the relevant part of) your input XML? And where is the variable `uID` defined?

Comment: Can you also show how you define the variable `uID`? Given your XML shows the output of the variables on different lines, one possibility is the values of the variables have line breaks at the end (and/or spaces) , which could affect the comparison. You could try `<xsl:if test="normalize-space($cID) = normalize-space($uID)">` to check if this was the case. Thank you.

Comment: @TimC you are correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tim C had the correct result.

uID was defined:

```
 <xsl:variable name="uID" select="id"/>
```

and had a whitespace which was solved with `<xsl:if test="normalize-space($cID) = normalize-space($uID)">`